# Hiding and showing existing or non-existing drives

Tags: windows, windows-7, registry

I'm playing around with the registry and found out i could hide drives from showing up at my computer using the key:
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
Then editing the data of the value:
NoDrives

Now i was wondering, is it possible to show non-existing drives in some way using registry?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it, it would not be very useful to have 20+ useless disk icons in My Computer.

Having a CD-ROM drive without a disc in it is pretty close and clicking on it by accident is rather annoying.

Comment: I am kind of agree with you about the logic of it. Even though i was kind of challenged to find a way of showing non-existent drives. I couldn't find the answer on google so I've came here to check if that is even possible.

Comment: The disk management UI will not allow you to assign a drive letter to something that does not exist. That does not technically prevent Explorer from showing virtual/pseudo disk items but it would require extra work on their end for no good reason.